# Effect on variance of change of measure

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, numerairechange

My current understanding:
(a) changing the probability measure of a diffusion process does not change the variance.
(b) for a general stochastic process the variance may change.
Please confirm whether this is correct.
Secondly, for (a) why isn't it important that there may be covariance between the asset being diffused and the value of the numeraire? (or the ratio of numeraires)?

Comment: Do you mean (co)variance or quadratic (co)variation? Also, "why isn't it important" in what regard, can you give an example of what "bothers" you?

Comment: For the first question, I mean the variance of the distribution after some time T.

Comment: And by diffusion process what do you mean exactly: no jumps? A specific form for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the SDE: $dS_t = \mu dt + \sigma dW_t$ e.g. no dependence on $S_t$ ?

Comment: yes, what restrictions on μ and σ in the SDE are necessary and sufficient for the varaince to stay constant under a change of measure?

Comment: Well the variance is not necessarily constant after a change or measure. Quadratic covariation is, at least under the conditions that underly the Girsanov theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) is true if measures are equivalent i.e. if $Pr(A)=0$ or $1$ in the first measure then it has to be the same in the other measure.

Being equivalent is always true when you change measure through the conventional radon-nikodym derivative.

Here's another way to see it:

The total probability of asset paths whose quadratic variation equals $σ^2$ is 1 in the first measure so has to be 1 in the second. Therefore variance is preserved.

The above hinges on the fact that quadratic variation of brownian motion is *almost surely (i.e. with probability 1) 1 per unit time*

If the stochastic process is different from brownian motion this may change.

(ii) the covariance between asset and the radon-nikodym derivative (or asset ratios) shows up as drift and not as vol. Covariance reflects systemic tie-up between the asset and the numeraire, so it biases the asset in terms of drift according to whether the covariance is positive or negative.